# How can I query the minute-value from a ISODate field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want write a query to find all records, if the minute-value of "dtg" is 0.

How can I do this?

an example record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6c42da787f7ad06a8a97ee"),
    "msgType" : "mos",
    "dtg" : ISODate("2018-08-09T16:00:00Z"),
    "stationId" : 10658,
    "weatherSituationId" : 0,
    "cloudAmount" : 4
}
```

Comment: Try `db.colname.find({$expr:{$eq:[{$minute:"$dtg"}, 0]}});` in 3.6 version.